# E(Xn)=infinity implies p-lim(Xn/n)=0?

Tags: random

I am struggling with an exercise… the first part of the exercise was ok, but the second part is a lot less trivial.

$X_n$ are non negative iid random variables.

First part: check that if $E(X_i)$ finite then $\lim X_n/n=0$ almost surely. I showed this using events $A_{k,\epsilon}=\{X_n>n\epsilon\}$, tail formula for $E(X_i)$ and 1st Borel Cantelli lemma.

Second part: on the other hand show that if $E(X_i)=\infty$ then $\operatorname*{p-lim} X_n/n =0 $ (that is $X_n/n \to 0$ in probability) but $P(\limsup X_n/n=\infty)=1$.

I get stuck on this one as it seems to contradict what I learnt in class. I try to use the 2nd Borel Cantelli lemma but can’t get to the conclusion.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for tips on formatting your post with MathJax to make it more readable.  See also [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  As it stands your question contains not much more than just the problem statement, which is likely to get closed.  Include more about what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

For the first half: let $X$ be a fixed random variable with the same distribution as the $X_n$ (you can take $X=X_1$ if you like).  Then $P(X_n/n \ge \epsilon) = P(X/n \ge \epsilon) = P(X \ge \epsilon n)$.  Show that this converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Hint: what can you say about $\bigcap_{n =1}^{\infty} \{X \ge \epsilon n\}$?

For the second half, start by showing the following lemma: if $X$ is any nonnegative random variable, then
$$E[X]-1 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X \ge n) \le E[X]$$
Hint: show $(X-1) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{X \ge n} \le X$ for each $\omega$, by considering what happens for each side when $k-1 \le X(\omega) < k$ for a given integer $k$.

Use this with the second Borel-Cantelli lemma to show that $P(X_n \ge n \text{ i.o.}) = 1$, which says that $\limsup X_n/n \ge 1$ almost surely.  Now repeat, replacing $X_n$ with $X_n/m$ for arbitrary $m$, to get $\limsup X_n/n \ge m$ a.s.  Finally take a countable intersection to get $\limsup X_n/n = \infty$ a.s.

Comment: Can you please clarify the last sentence? To get from $limsupX_n/n>=m$ a.s. to $limsup = infinity$ a.s.?

Comment: @JenniferK: Let $A_m = \{ \limsup X_n/n \ge m\}$.  We showed $P(A_m) = 1$.  Let $A = \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_m$; then $P(A)=1$ and on $A$ we have $\limsup X_n/n = \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! 
Wouldn’t it be enough to say that $P(A_m)=1 $ for any m including very large m and thus $ P(limsupX_n/n= infinity)=1$ ?

Comment: @JenniferK: That's the basic idea, yes.  I just wanted to be clear about the details.  We're using the countable additivity of $P$ (the claim is not true for finitely additive measures) and so it's important that we only need to know $\limsup X_n/n \ge m$ for a *countable* set of values for $m$.  (Formatting hint: use `\limsup` and `\infty`.)

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the formatting tips!